# Merge nested lists into a data frame maintaining higher order list structure

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply, do.call

I have a a list composed of nested lists. Each of these nested lists contains data frames that share the same columns. I want to merge the data frames within each nested list , maintaining the higher order list.

I've tried doing this with lapply and do.call, but it's taking far too long. Indeed I'm getting the following error:

> Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)

```
my.list <- replicate(100, replicate(10, data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 6:10), simplify = F), simplify = F)
my.list <- lapply(my.list, function(l) do.call("rbind", l))
```

This gives me exactly the data structure I want, but runs way too slow with large data.

Comment: Can you check `rbindlist` from `data.table` and see if there is any improvement? `lapply(my.list, data.table::rbindlist)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to use `purrr::map` with `dplyr::bind_rows`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(my.list, bind_rows)
```

Here is a `microbenchmark` comparison of the different methods

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)    

library(microbenchmark)
res <- microbenchmark(
    lapply_do_call_rbind = {
        lapply(my.list, function(l) do.call("rbind", l))
    },
    map_bind_rows = {
        map(my.list, bind_rows)
    },
    lapply_rbindlist = {
        lapply(my.list, rbindlist)
    }
)
#Unit: milliseconds
#                 expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq
# lapply_do_call_rbind 46.104965 49.801469 54.567249 51.815901 54.085547
#        map_bind_rows  3.257474  3.490079  4.055779  3.620804  4.002505
#     lapply_rbindlist  9.446331 10.009678 11.429870 10.796956 12.252741

library(ggplot2)
autoplot(res)
```

[image]